# renderEvent not rendering new event

Tags: fullcalendar

I have code like this:

```
dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {

        console.log(moment.utc(date).format());
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', {
            title: 'sds',
            start: moment.utc(date).format(),
            allDay: false,
            lazyFetching: false
        }, true);

    },
```

And new event never shows. I want to create event so I can manipulate it. I need it just for a representation of time in space - any ideas why it doesn't work?

Comment: @Adyson's answer is correct for the question and code you've shown.  If you're still having problems, maybe there's something related you're not showing us.  You mention `renderEvent` in the title of your question - are you doing something with that in your code?

Comment: It was related to `events` - if they generate error it won't work (surprisingly).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/utc/ - the "utc" function doesn't accept a parameter. I suspect your event *is* getting created, but on today's date instead of the date you clicked. I suspect you meant `moment(date).utc()`, which would pass the date into moment's constructor and create a moment on that date.

However since `date` is already a momentJS object (as per https://fullcalendar.io/docs/mouse/dayClick/), you can just call `.utc()` on it directly anyway, without the constructor. You should do `date.utc()` to set it, before you pass it to your event.

Overall:

```
dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {
  date.utc(); //set date to utc first

  $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', {
    title: 'sds',
    start: date.format(),
    allDay: false,
    lazyFetching: false
  }, true);
},
```

Comment: Still when clicking nothing happens - not sure what could be blocking it

Comment: any other errors in your browser console? My code as above, definitely works - see http://jsfiddle.net/sbxpv25p/33/

Comment: Okay, now I see my error. When refreshing page I put wrong `events` source to keep calendar clean before selecting from dropdown. When I select source and events render then all works fine. Thanks a lot!